# Drag and Drop Audio file in NSTableView Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I want to drag and drop the audio songs from desktop to the nstableview, i tried the following methods, i want to know how to check the file type is audio and How to append these new files into Library.xml

```
- (NSDragOperation) tableView: (NSTableView *)tv validateDrop: (id <NSDraggingInfo>)info proposedRow: (NSInteger)row proposedDropOperation: (NSTableViewDropOperation)op
{
[tv setDropRow:[tv numberOfRows] dropOperation:NSTableViewDropAbove];
return NSTableViewDropAbove;
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView acceptDrop:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)info row:(NSInteger)row dropOperation:(NSTableViewDropOperation)dropOperation
{
NSPasteboard *myPasteboard=[info draggingPasteboard];
NSArray *typeArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSFilenamesPboardType,nil];
NSString *filePath,*availableType,*lastPathOfFileName;
NSArray *filesList;
int i;
availableType=[myPasteboard availableTypeFromArray:typeArray];
filesList=[myPasteboard propertyListForType:availableType];
for (i=0;i<[filesList count];i++)
{
    filePath=[filesList objectAtIndex:i];
    lastPathOfFileName=[filePath lastPathComponent];
    NSUInteger No = 1;

    [mySongsArray insertObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",No],@"No",
                                @"testName",@"Name",
                                @"5.0",@"Time",
                                @"Ar.rahman",@"Artist",
                                @"hariharan",@"Album",
                                @"English",@"Genre",nil]  atArrangedObjectIndex:row];
}
testArray = [mySongsArray arrangedObjects];
NSLog(@"testArray===%@",[testArray description]);
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's confusing and entirely unreadable - can you pls paste everything into the question?

Comment: Arun, edit the question and paste.

Comment: NSArray *muarray = [zPBoard propertyListForType:DragandDropSongs];
        NSData *newData =[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[muarray objectAtIndex:0]]; 
        NSUInteger No = 1;
        [mySongsArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",No],@"No", [audioFile title],@"Name", nil]];
        [libraryTableView reloadData];

Comment: You are always using 1 for "No" and audioFile title as name. How are you getting the audioFile object. You no where using the newData.